# how can I filter the difference between the two models? using django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 models, **Product** and **ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct** , the **Product** have 5 data, [chicken, okra, ampalaya, cabbage] and the **ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct** have [chicken, okra, cabbage] how do i get the remaining data in **Product** that dont have in **ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct** ?

[image]

*the choosen product is **ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct** and the list of product is **Product***

I just want that the data displayed on the choosen product should no longer be visible in the product list.

so far this is my views.py

```
def searchrelatedproduct(request):
    id = request.GET.get('relatedproductID')
    products = Product.objects.all()
    relatedproduct = ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct.objects.filter(productrelatedgroup = id)
    return render(request, "customAdmin/relatedproduct.html",{"products":products,"relatedproduct":relatedproduct})
```

this is my html

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="/GroupOfProduct/" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
  <h2>Product </h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <br>
      <label for="sel2">List Of Products</label>
            <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel2" name="product">
                {% for product in products %}
                    <option>{{product.product}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
    </div>
      <input type="submit" style="float:right;">
  </form>
</div>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Choosen Product</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="/UpdateGroupOfProduct/" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
      <input type="submit" style="float:right;">
    <div class="form-group">
      <br>
      <label for="sel2">List Of Choosen Products</label>
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="sel2" name="relatedproduct">
          {% for product in relatedproduct %}

            <option value="{{ product.id }}">{{product.product}}</option>
          {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

this is my models.py

```
class ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True,blank=True,verbose_name="Product")
   productrelatedgroup = models.ForeignKey('ProductGroup',
                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,
                            verbose_name="ProductGroup")
class Product(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=500)


class ProductGroup(models.Model):

    category = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

UPDATE

when i tried this

```
diffproducts = products.exclude(pk__in=relatedproduct)
print(diffproducts)
```

it prints all data of the Product

```
<QuerySet [<Product: cabbage>, <Product: ampalaya>, <Product: okra>, <Product: Chicken>]>
```

and when i tried this

```
unused_product = set(relatedproduct).difference(set(products))
print(unused_product)

***result***
{<ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct: cabbage>, <ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct: ampalaya>, <ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct: okra>}
```

and this

```
Product.objects.filter(productrelatedgroupandproduct__isnull=True)
```

i get this error

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'productrelatedgroupandproduct' into field
```

Comment: share your models.py.

Comment: okay please wait

Comment: @djangotic checked my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships) for filter:

```
Product.objects.filter(productrelatedgroupandproduct__isnull=True)
```

`productrelatedgroupandproduct` here is a lowercased name of `ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct` model. It's default value for [related_query_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name) argument.

Comment: Ive tried this but i get this result *** <QuerySet [<ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct: cabbage>, <ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct: ampalaya>, <ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct: okra>]> ***

Comment: @justin are you sure you did `Product.objects.filter(productrelatedgroupandproduct__isnull=True)`? Because it returns Queryset of `Product` objects. But you said it returns `ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct`.

Comment: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'productrelatedgroupandproduct' into field

Comment: In my Product model, i dont have foreignkey of ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct

Comment: @justin but since you have foreign key of `Product` in `ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct `, you can use `productrelatedgroupandproduct` to filter `Product`. Check links from my answer. As for `Cannot resolve keyword 'productrelatedgroupandproduct'` did you show your actual code? Probably model has diffrent name?

Comment: no , in your answer , since i dont have a foreignkey of ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct  in my Product that is why i receive that error

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible by converting your queryset to a set and then use `intersection` for complex cases.

```
# get objects present in both
set(products).intersection(set(relatedproduct))


# get product not in relatedproduct
set(products).difference(set(relatedproduct))


# opposite
set(relatedproduct).difference(set(products))
```

In your case `exclude` can do the trick:
`products.exclude(pk__in=relatedproduct)`

Comment: how do i use the set(relatedproduct).difference(set(products))?

Comment: within your `searchrelatedproduct` like: `unused_product = set(relatedproduct).difference(set(products)) ` and then pass it in the return as you did for products. Then loop through then in the template

Comment: it prints all data

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exclude function :

views.py:

```
def searchrelatedproduct(request):
    id = request.GET.get('relatedproductID')
    products = Product.objects.all()
    relatedproduct = ProductRelatedGroupAndProduct.objects.filter(pk=id)
    diffproducts = products.exclude(pk__in=relatedproduct)

    return render(request, "test.html",{"products":diffproducts,"relatedproduct":relatedproduct})
```

and output in template in your orignal html.

Comment: It prints all data just like this <QuerySet [<Product: cabbage>, <Product: ampalaya>, <Product: okra>, <Product: Chicken>]>

Comment: Like a queryset. Updated my answer wtith html

Comment: it prints all data,

Comment: answer updated. what is the url of your test? did you pass relatedproductId ?

Comment: ive post the my full models.py please check my updated question

Comment: OK, what is this id : id = request.GET.get('relatedproductID') ? an id of a list of products ?

Comment: no, the id of product category ""productrelatedgroup"" ive post my updated models.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220100/discussion-between-justin-and-eric-martin).